# Why does rotation take abrupt jump?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

This is a WPF desktop app. I'm using `Thumb` control to rotate my objects. While it works nice and smooth in general, there is an abrupt jump in the rotation angle every time I start rotating. After the initial jump, rotation works smoothly again.

Very easy to reproduce. Here is complete XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Width="600" Height="600">
  <Canvas>
    <ContentControl x:Name="CC" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="300">
      <Grid>
        <Thumb DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta">
          <Thumb.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
              <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red" Margin="0,-150,0,0" />
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Thumb.Template>
        </Thumb>

        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Fill="Yellow" />
      </Grid>

      <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="RT" />
      </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
    </ContentControl>
  </Canvas>
</Window>
```

And here is complete code-behind:

```
Imports System.Windows.Controls.Primitives

Class TestWindow
  Inherits Window

  Private Sub Thumb_DragDelta(sender As Object, e As Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs)
    Dim T = DirectCast(sender, Thumb)
    Dim RT = DirectCast(CC.RenderTransform, RotateTransform)

    Dim Pos = Mouse.GetPosition(Me)
    Dim PCenter As New Point(350, 350) 'Center of yellow square

    Dim xDiff = Pos.X - PCenter.X
    Dim yDiff = Pos.Y - PCenter.Y
    Dim angle = Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * 180.0 / Math.PI
    RT.Angle = angle + 90
  End Sub
End Class
```

Click on the red thumb and rotate. It works nicely. Stop rotating at an arbitrary angle. Click th red thumb again and start rotating. Rotation will take a big jump initially and then start rotating smoothly again.

Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RotateTransform` origin doesn't match the center point used in the code-behind.

The transform origin is located at the top left corner by default and is `(300; 300)`, not `(350; 350)`.
This leads to an invalid angle calculation when the initial angle is not zero.

Use

```
<ContentControl x:Name="CC" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="300" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
    <!--...-->
</ContentControl>
```

---

### UPDATE

If you cannot change the `RenderTransformOrigin`, then you need to correct the angle calculation in code-behind.

First of all, use the proper center point:

```
Dim PCenter As New Point(300, 300)
```

Then keep in mind, that your thumb doesn't actually correspond to the angle you want your object to rotate to. The thumb has an offset. You need to take that into account.

```
Dim offsetAngle = Math.Atan2(-25.0, 50.0) * 180 / Math.PI
Dim angle = Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * 180.0 / Math.PI - offsetAngle 
RT.Angle = angle
```

You can make `offsetAngle` to a `const` (not sure how to do this in VB).

Where those `-25.0` and `50.0` come from? `50.0` is the horizontal offset of the thumb calculated as `Grid.ActualWidth / 2.0` (because the thumb is horizontally centered). `-25.0` is the vertical offset of the thumb calculated as `(Grid.ActualHeight + Thumb.Margin.Top) / 2.0` (because the thumb is above the `Grid`).

Comment: I can't change `RenderTransformOrigin` since I need to rotate around the top-left corner. Can we do some adjustment in the code-behind to make that work?

Comment: I tried using `CenterX` and `CenterY` properties of my `RotateTransform`. Those too, like `RenderTransformOrigin` work only if I set them to the center of the square. There must be some way to rotate smoothly around the top-left corner.

Comment: What if you want to rotate around the center again (without changing `RenderTransformOrigin`)? I tried by setting PCenter to (350,350) and offset to (-75, 0), but it doesn't rotate around the center.